# Externally target (URL) and expand panel/accordion Boostrap. Not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Really going crazy and I must be overlooking something, but I have no clue what.

I am trying to make my panel expand after clicking on an external link, for example:

```
http://domain.com/test.php#headingTwo
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                  <h4 class="panel-title greylinks">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                      Example text #1
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Ipsem lorem whatever #1....</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                  <h4 class="panel-title greylinks">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                      Example text #2
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Ipsem lorem whatever #2....</p> 
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                  <h4 class="panel-title greylinks">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                      Example text #3
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Ipsem lorem whatever #3....</p> 
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
```

And the JS is like this:

```
<script>
var activateAccordion = function (id) {
    // Get the parents
    var parents = $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parents('.panel-group').children('.panel');

    // Go through each of the parents
    $.each(parents, function (idx, obj) {
        // Check if the child exists
        var find = $(obj).find('a[href="#' + id + '"]'),
            children = $(obj).children('.panel-collapse');

        if (find.length > 0) {
            // Show the selected child
            children.removeClass('collapse');
            children.addClass('in');
        } else {
            // Hide the others
            children.removeClass('in');
            children.addClass('collapse');
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

No matter what I do it seems to ignore the link completely.
It does go to the correct panel, however it doesn't expand the panel.

I must be overlooking something, but after several hours fooling around I cannot see it anymore. Probably some small typo somewhere.

Update
Added jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/22648/

And in case someone misunderstood me, I am trying to create a link in email and once clicked it should load the website and go to the opened panel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, when i read first time i wrong understood what u want, try this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var getHash = location.hash; //get hash from js object location

function activateAccordion (id) 
{
    if(id.length)//check if hash isn't empty
    {
        var accordion = $('a[href="' + id + '"]');
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: accordion.parents('.panel').offset().top //scroll to accordion
        }, 500,function(){
            accordion.click(); //simulate click
        });
    }
};

activateAccordion(getHash);
```

});

**UPDATE: added scroll to accordeon...whe scroll animation complete accordeon opens**

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/22719/)

Comment: I re-read your comment several times, but I don't understand what you mean. I have data-toggle="collapse" in every panel included...?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Highly appreciated. Though one (minor) issue... It opens the panel, however it doesn't scroll down to the opened panel. Is there a solution for this. If I refresh the page it does scroll down, but not when clicking the link in the email?

For some reason, when clicking the link in the email, it doesn't scroll down to the content...?

Comment: u need when page loaded. smooth scroll to accordeon and then opening accordeon ?

Comment: Whatever is the most easiest to do... Currently it only goes to the section when you hit F5 (refresh). If I click the link it opens the accordeon panel, but doesn't go to it. If copy the link and place it in the browser, it does? Weird...

Comment: Wow.... This is excellent! I couldn't have done this better! The result is even better than expected! Highly appreciated. Thanks Ivan!